# ClickOnce: How do you tell the user what the newest version is?

Tags: clickonce

I have my ClickOnce application set to check for updates after it runs. Is there a way to prompt the user to tell them they aren't on the current version?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's some example code here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.checkforupdatecompletedeventargs.aspx

You can use the [AvailableVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.checkforupdatecompletedeventargs.availableversion(v=VS.80).aspx) property of CheckForUpdateCompletedEventArgs to learn the new version.